# How do I open a Windows Application ".exe" file in Visual Basic to see the code?

Tags: visual-studio

I have a Windows Application .exe file (that was made in Visual Studio) and a .mdf file in the same folder (not sure if the .mdf file matters).

How can I open up this Windows Application in Visual Studio to see the code and how it works?

Comment: There are a bunch of different programs out there to achieve this. If the software itself isn't protected, try for example Telerik JustDecompile (which is free), it will do what you like. You can't open it in Visual Studio. And if the code is obfuscated you'll have a hard time following the code, but as I said Before, try JustDecompile from http://www.telerik.com

Comment: once the code is compiled you can't get the original code anymore because it isn't stored in binary. Sometimes a [decompiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decompiler) can work but generally one would need to [reverse engineer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_engineering) the binary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a decompiler to decompile it and then you can see the code of file but it doesn't show you the original code. If you are good with assembler you can use  disassembler tools to view the code in ansembler and modify it.

Comment: I was able to decompile it, but it was not the original code like you said. It was much harder for me to read/understand, so I wasn't able to use it. Oh well. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

.exe files are compiled binary code and cannot be read without a special program called a decompiler.